# Cordova Platform add android gives Error: Your android platform does not have Api.js

Tags: android, cordova

I have updated cordova to 7.0.1 in windows 8.1
After creating project when i add platform using this command

```
cordova platform add android
```

It gives me following error

```
 Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-android is deprecated. Upgrade to cordova-android@5.0.0 or newer.
 Error: Your android platform does not have Api.js
```

I tried to search it on forums but didn't get it resolved.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042641/cordova-error-your-ios-platform-does-not-have-api-js

Comment: I keep running into this issue when I `git checkout` to another branch. Is there a cause for this error?

Answer (score 12):

I think you have **cordova-android** version older than 5.
Try to force cordova update:

```
npm install -g cordova@7.0.0
```

then try to readd **cordova-android**:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work.
I downgrade my Cordova. but that is not solution

Comment: Try to launch "cordova platform version android" and "cordova --version" command from root of your project. What version of cordova-android is displayed?

Answer (score 4):

run

```
$ sudo npm uninstall cordova -g
```

and

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova@6.0.0
```

I did not get another solution

Comment: It was working while I have an older version of Cordova, but the error comes after upgrading Cordova to 7. A downgrade is not a solution of my question.

Comment: [don't use `sudo` with `npm`](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92)

Answer (score 4):

Run this at your terminal

```
ionic cordova platform rm .idea
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply just

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```