# Cordova Error: Your ios platform does not have Api.js

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I'm trying to build a cordova ios app but not having much luck and getting strange errors.

> Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-ios is
> deprecated. Upgrade to cordova-ios@4.0.0 or newer.
>
> Error: Your ios platform does not have Api.js

The first warning says my cordov-ios version is old, which is strange as this is my output:

```
$ cordova --version
7.0.1



$ cordova platform version ios

Installed platforms:
  ios 4.4.0
Available platforms: 
  android ~6.2.2
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~4.1.0
  osx ~4.0.1
  webos ~3.7.0
```

So I clearly have the latest versions necessary.

And then the `Api.js` error. What is causing this?

> Error: Your ios platform does not have Api.js

Any ideas?

Comment: your _cordova-ios_ is deprecated..not cordova cli.. maybe try `cordova platform add ios@latest` ?

Comment: thanks suraj. But my cordova-ios version is 4.4.0, so how is it deprecated? It's the latest no?

Comment: @andy Please accept the answer which worked for you atleast your accepted answer will help someone. thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm guessing that attempting to use deprecated code is the reason for seeing the error message.

It appears that one should be using the latest version of node.  I also performed all my software updates for Xcode.  I also connected my iPhone to my computer. Even after that (and before I updated node) I was still seeing this:

```
cordova platform add ios

Warning: using node version v0.12.0 which has been deprecated. Please upgrade to the latest node version available (v6.x is recommended).
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^4.4.0
Adding ios project...
Error: Your ios platform does not have Api.js
```

Then I decided to resolve the warning by [updating node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version).  And finally success:

```
sudo n latest
node --version
=> v8.0.0

cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios

Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.4.0
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: com.example.hello
    Name: HelloWorld
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.4.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving ios@~4.4.0 into config.xml file ...
```

Comment: I was struggling with this "Your ios platform does not have Api.js" error, and this was finally the fix for me. I was building remote using Visual Studio and updating node on MacOS fixed the issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: I had similar issue in browser solution, same worked

Comment: I tried  cordova platform rm/add android.......Failed to install 'mx.ferreyra.callnumber': Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (The platform ".gradle" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. .gradle not supported.) My Versions on Ubuntu : 
+ node -v
v9.2.1
+ cordova -v
7.1.0
+ npm -v
5.5.1
+ gradle -v
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.3

Answer (score 74):

I was having exactly this problem but managed to solve it by simply removing and then adding the IOS platform within my project:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

This seemed to fix whatever had somehow got broken when updating Cordova...

Comment: I tried this approach, but it didn't work for me.  Explicitly updating node seemed to be the key point in my case.

Comment: Without sudo access `cordova platform rm ios` would give the following error `rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): /Users/xyz/abc/platforms/ios` - with sudo it worked.

Comment: but you will need to `chown` the files back to user

Comment: This approach worked for me, I've removed all the platforms. Added back iOS and the installation was success without this error. It was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Has same issue with latest version of cordova (7.0.1)

Faced error while adding iOS platform and managed to resolve it by upgrading nodeJS to latest version (6.11.1)

Comment: Thanks for this. Upgrading to the v6 LTS release from 6.9.2 worked for me too.

Comment: @c0bra glad it was helpful. Cheers

Comment: @AshishKarpe what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can also occur when you have both the Android and iOS installed. At least this was the case for me.

When I ran the command:

`cordova platform rm android`

It started to work

Comment: I had to remove both android and browser platforms, and then adding ios worked.

Answer (score 1):

use cordova@6.0 solved the problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 1):

For those of you that have tried updating your NodeJs and that didn't work.

Go check in your platforms/android or platforms/ios folder. Mine was empty. Delete the folder, and run `ionic cordova add android/ios` again.

Answer (score 1):

Downgraded to cordova 8 and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I always fix this error removing the platform and adding it again (android in my case)

```
phonegap platform rm android
```

wait until it finishes...

```
phonegap platform add android
```

And that´s it. Let me know if it is fixed for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in Windows 10 trying to run a "cordova plugins add ..." command to my android/ios app. I had the latest Node/NPM already and did not want to platform rm/add again. Instead I tried the "cordova plugins add ..." command on my OSX laptop instead of Windows 10 ... and it worked. No idea how/why but thankful it worked. Realize this may not help most w/this error but maybe someone else out there in same boat.