# Cordova iOS platform does not have Api.js

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, cordova, npm

I am trying to add an iOS platform to a new Cordova 7.0.1 project but keep getting the error listed in the title of this post.  I have tried removing the platform and adding it as suggested in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042641/cordova-error-your-ios-platform-does-not-have-api-js), but I still get the error.  I recently upgraded Cordova from 6.5.0 to 7.0.1 and since then this error has come up.  Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Node.js to the latest version.

Comment: This was the problem.  My node was on version 0.12.x  Upgrading to 6.11.x fixed this issue.

Comment: Make also sure that Cordova is installed globally

Answer (score 1):

Please remove and then add the iOS platform within project:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Hope this might be help you. It worked for me.

Comment: I have tried that and it did not fix it for me.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
cordova platform update ios
```

This worked for me fine