# Getting an error 'Unable to load PlatformApi from platform; when trying to convert an angular app using cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am trying to convert my angular app to andriod app using cordova

when issuing the *command*:

```
cordova build android
```

it gives the below *error*:

```
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module 'properties-parser'
Unhandled error. ('The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.')
```

what should I do ?

Comment: have you tried - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042641/cordova-error-your-ios-platform-does-not-have-api-js ??

Comment: did an npm update and it worked.

Comment: removing and adding platform again worked for me.
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android

Answer (score 1):

Removing and adding platform should work.

cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android